# Can stock .Net installations open Access databases?

Tags: .net, ms-access

I am wondering if the driver mentioned here would be on a PC running .Net 2.0 or higher:

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p4.html

could I deploy an application that accesses an access database in this manner?

Thanks

Comment: Some additional links: [Establishing the Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254507.aspx), [OleDbConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx), [Connection String Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on a program that writes the reports to the .mdb database in this manner. All works fine.

Small contribution:
if database has password, add "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mypasswordhere" to connection string

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add a reference to System.DataOleDb. It's in the `Add References` dialog, under `.NET Framework`.

Comment: Don't you mean `System.Data.OleDb`?